# Installing node on elementary os

Tags: software-installation, elementary-os, node.js

Right now when I run `node -v` I get `4.2.6`.  This is after having run:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Elementary is an Ubuntu based distro.  So I thought these [directions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) would work.

How can I install node 6.2.0?

Comment: Apart from an advice [not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29389868 "why using curl | sudo sh is not advised?") to pipe scripts from the internet to a root shell: what does `type node` say? Maybe this `setup_6.x` thing installs to a different location and your call to `node -v` still runs an old version in your `PATH`?

Comment: `node is hashed (/usr/local/bin/node)`.   Considering those directions come from `https://nodejs.org/` I think its safe.

Comment: If `node` is hashed to `/usr/local/bin/node`, then chances are my guess was correct, because often `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in `PATH`, and the new `node` will be installed to `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/posts/480642/edit).

Use [n module from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) in order to upgrade node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/<VERSION>/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

To upgrade to latest version (and not current stable) version, you can use

```
sudo n latest
```

### To undo:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy     # fix /usr/bin/node
sudo n rm 6.0.0     # replace number with version of Node that was installed
sudo npm uninstall -g n
```

Found in David Walsh blog
http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs